# I got Error on submitting query after complete install of Messagebundle in my project

Tags: php, symfony

I got yhis type of error :

ContextErrorException: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/imsdemo/vendor/friendsofsymfony/message-bundle/FOS/MessageBundle/Entity/Thread.php line 81

please help me to solve this Error...

```
protected function getParticipantsCollection()
{
    if ($this->participants == null) {
        $this->participants = new ArrayCollection();

/* Line 81*/ foreach ($this->metadata as $data) {
             $this->participants->add($data->getParticipant());
             }

    }

    return $this->participants;
}
```

this the code which give error

Comment: Please provide your code. What is on line 81 ?!

Comment: please see i have added code in it @LorenzMeyer

Comment: $this->metadata should be an array, but it isn't. You have to follow back in your code. The function print_debug_backtrace() could be useful.

Comment: I have also do as is_array($this->metadata) but it give me something like 'You are not allowed to see this thread' message in the link http://example.com/app_dev.php/messages/1 in my project

Comment: @LorenzMeyer you get any idea how it occurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Issue why is happening because of whenever I do schema update of database its taking the MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine YML file which not update my database as FosMessageBundle has...so when i had remove the /config/doctrine folder and then do the schema update It is working fine ...